# Access violation in custom comparator in priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have an issue were a program of mine throws an access violation.
Through debugging I found that for some reason the comparator-function is null.
However I am not sure on why that is or how to fix it.

I created a minimum working example to reproduce the issue:

```
#include "Tryout.h"
#include <queue>

struct Event {
    uint64_t mv_timeout;
};

bool CompareEvents(const Event& a, const Event& b) {
    return a.mv_timeout < b.mv_timeout;
}

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, decltype(&CompareEvents)> mt_eventQueue;
    Event lo_event1{
        .mv_timeout = 1,
    };
    Event lo_event2{
        .mv_timeout = 2,
    };
    mt_eventQueue.push(lo_event1);
    mt_eventQueue.push(lo_event2);
    return 0;
}
```

When executing it crashes when adding the second event.

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in Tryout.exe: 0xC0000005:
> Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.

As mentioned it seems the comparing function is null, even tough I passed it via template.
What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the comparison function explicitly in the constructor

```
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, decltype(&CompareEvents)> mt_eventQueue( CompareEvents );
```

Otherwise the default argument will be used for the comparison function that will yield a null pointer.

The used constructor has the following declaration with default arguments

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x = Compare(), Container&& = Container());
```

Comment: That was a simple solution - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The template argument for the comparator function only provides the function's type, you still need to supply an actual function matching that type to an instance of `std::priority_queue` (via its [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)).

If you define a less-than operator yourself, then you don't need to explicitly supply any other template arguments for `std::priority_queue`.

For example:

```cpp
struct Event
{
    uint64_t mv_timeout;
};

bool operator<(const Event &a, const Event &b)
{
    return a.mv_timeout < b.mv_timeout;
}

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<Event> mt_eventQueue;
    Event lo_event1{
        .mv_timeout = 1,
    };
    Event lo_event2{
        .mv_timeout = 2,
    };
    mt_eventQueue.push(lo_event1);
    mt_eventQueue.push(lo_event2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as your comparator function is not a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses), you should pass your comparator function in the constructor of `std::priority:queue`.

```
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, decltype(&CompareEvents)> mt_eventQueue(CompareEvents);
```

If your comparator was a something like this

```
struct CompareEvents
{
    bool operator()(const Event& a, const Event& b) {
        return a.mv_timeout < b.mv_timeout;
    }
}
```

You could have created the queue without specifying the functor, as far as it would be deduced by default constructor of `CompareEvents`,(as stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)).

```
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, CompareEvents> mt_eventQueue; //this works
```